# Why python 2 and 3 have different print outputs for some hex values?

Tags: python

I found this while doing pwnable.kr. I wonder why two python versions would output differently?

```
python2.7 -c "print '\xbe\xba\xfe\xca'"
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obo9A.png)

```
python3.6 -c "print('\xbe\xba\xfe\xca')"
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZiwU.png)

Comment: What you're printing isn't hex. You've used hex notation to express the objects you're printing, but what you're printing is not hex.

Comment: Sorry for my ambiguous words. To rephrase, I was trying to print some data and pipe them to netcat. Not printing hex in string representation.

Answer (score 1):

In Python2.x the output you see is basically error thrown while decoding the string.

The string ('\xbe\xba\xfe\xca') that you have will throw UnicodeDecodeError if you want to parse it.
Whereas in Python3.x, all strings are automatically Unicode so there is no error thrown.

Comment: Thanks, I think I get it now. When I pipe the output to netcat, py2 gave the original data but py3 didn't. Is that because py3 did some processing?